# How can I use Django dynamic IDs in Javascript/Ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, django, ajax, dynamic

I have a Django HTML file like this:

```
 <button type="button" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" class="btn btn-primary form-control">{{ choice.choice_text }}</button>
```

I have an Ajax .js file like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#choice{{ forloop.counter }}').on('click', function(){
(...)
```

Where {{ forloop.counter }} obviously don't work.

What I could use to replace it in ajax?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="llamar_funcion('{{ forloop.counter }}')">


<script type="text/javascript">
    function llamar_funcion(id)

    ...
</script>
```